# F# convert Array2 into a list

Tags: list, f#

I'm still new to functional programming so if I can't figure out how to do something I revert back to procedural style.  I found a way to get around having to convert to a list but I'd still like to know how.

Here is my attempt to convert a two dimensional array to a list.

```
let board = Array2.init 10 20 (fun i j -> pull(i, j))

let mutable pieces = []

board
|> Array2.mapi (fun i j a -> transform(i, j, a))
|> Array2.iter (fun a -> (pieces <- a :: pieces))
```

Comment: where's Array2 in .NET? If it's your function, could you provide source? Thanks

Comment: I believe it has been renamed to Array2D. It's in the F# runtime.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353794.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently in .Net, multi-dimensional arrays are IEnumerable (non-generic), and thus this works:

```
let a2 = Array2.init 2 3 (fun x y -> (x+1)*(y+1))
let l = a2 |> Seq.cast<int> |> Seq.fold (fun l n -> n :: l) []
printfn "%A" l
```

EDIT: As Noldorin points out in a comment, this is even better:

```
let l = a2 |> Seq.cast<int> |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Good solution... I've just deleted mine, as it's slightly more complicated. However I might as well point out that the second line can be simplified to: let l = a2 |> Seq.cast<int> |> Seq.to_list

Comment: Awesome thanks, I figured there was something I could do with IEnumerable but I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: its `Seq.toList` not `Seq.to_list`.. (can't edit because SO says: `Edits must be at least 6 characters`, thank you very much SO.. :/ )