# How to convert a 2d array to a list of lists in F#

Tags: f#

I have a 2d array of floats:

```
let scores  = Array2D.init<float> width height (fun _ _ -> 0.)
```

and I would like to convert it to a list of lists where I have a list of rows and each of these row is a list of column values.

for example:

```
[
  1, 2, 3
  4, 5, 6
  7, 8, 9
]
```

would become:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3]
  [4, 5, 6]
  [7, 8, 9]
]
```

I found this question: [F# convert Array2 into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648193/f-convert-array2-into-a-list)

but it converts the 2d array into a list, I'm trying to find how to convert it to a list of list.
I could iterate through the elements and build the list, but I'm sure there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made quite readable by F#'s slice operators (now in C# 8 too!).
To slice a multi-dimensional array you can use `.[range,range]`.

For example, `.[*,n]` for the n-th column, and `.[n,*]` for the n-th row.

The final piece we need is the height of the array, which is Dimension 0, given by

```
array.GetLength 0
```

Now it becomes trivial to slice up the 2D array, using a list comprehension.

```
[ 
    let height = arr.GetLength 0
    for row in 0..height-1  do
    yield arr.[row,*] |> List.ofArray
]
```

For non-zero indexed arrays, as suggested by Henrik Hansen, it is preferable to use:

```
[ 
    for i in arr.GetLowerBound(0)..arr.GetUpperBound(0) 
        do yield arr.[i,*] |> List.ofArray 
]
```

**Test**

```
let counter = ref 0
//generate the test array
let arr = Array2D.init (3) (3) (fun _ _ -> Interlocked.Increment(counter))

arr |> printfn "%A"  

let lists = 
    [ 
        let height = arr.GetLength 0
        for row in 0..height - 1  do
        yield arr.[row,*] |> List.ofArray
    ]

lists |> printfn "%A"
```

Output:

```
[[1; 2; 3]
 [4; 5; 6]
 [7; 8; 9]]

[[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6]; [7; 8; 9]]
```

Comment: Does the start-to-end slice range `*` still work when the base-index for the second dimension is not 0?

Comment: @kaefer It does respect lower bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Another way building on Asti's ideas:

```
module Array2D =
    let toListOfLists (arr2d: 'a [,]) = [ yield! [arr2d.GetLowerBound(0)..arr2d.GetUpperBound(0)] |> List.map (fun i -> arr2d.[i,*] |> List.ofArray) ]

let base002D = Array2D.init 5 5 (fun x y -> (x, y))
let base152D = Array2D.initBased 1 5 5 5 (fun x y -> (x, y)) 

printfn "%A" (base002D |> Array2D.toListOfLists)
printfn "%A" (base152D |> Array2D.toListOfLists)
```

It works with different bases.

Comment: Maybe simpler to just use a single list comprehension? `[ for i in arr2d.GetLowerBound(0)..arr2d.GetUpperBound(0) do yield arr2d.[i,*] |> List.ofArray ]`

Comment: @Asti: yes, that will do too. The important thing is just, that we'll have to use upper and lower bounds to make it able to handle bases other than zero.

Comment: Absolutely. Although non-zero indexed arrays are relatively rare, and most array code written generally assumes zero-indexing.